# Reset password not working in magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2, frontend-error, password-recovery, forgot-password

The reset password is not working, I'm receiving the email, and reset link is working. After entering the new password and submit, it says that the password reset link has expired.

I'm using Porto theme.

[image]

Please find screenshot.

Thanks

Comment: - Try changing to the default magneto theme to see if it does the same. Also  try disabling all the custom module to see if it still does the same thing. Something else you can do check the cookies configuration and check the configuration about the time the link is valid , its in store / config/customer settings.

Comment: @VyacheslavShmal Its is working when I switched the theme to luma. I believe the issue is with Porto theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to fix this issue with Porto theme.

I renamed the below two files, and clear caches and it starts working again.

app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Customer/templates/form/forgotpassword.phtml

app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Customer/templates/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml

Answer (score 0):

@sandeep you saved my life! This issue is very difficult to find the problem, and the first thing that I did was to try luma teme, and the problem is the same.

Renaming or deleting these two port files solves the problem! Everything works without any problem and I didn't notice any missing files.

I will investigate what changed in magento that caused these problems in the theme.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to hear this.

Renaming those files will not create any issues.